# In C, can a segmentation fault occur only for out of bound access in heap area? Or can it happen even for static arrays in a stack?

Tags: c, debugging, segmentation-fault, ram

I gather from previous answers on SO that seg fault occurs due to deferencing a NULL pointer or due to out-of-bounds array access. But does it happen only for dynamically declared arrays or also for statically declared ones?

Answer (score 1):

It is not always necessary that you get segmentation fault when you try to access an array out of bounds.

It all depends upon the memory location that is being referred to. Segmentation is a protection mechanism. When you are trying to enter into another process area, the MMU or MPU will catch such access and raises an access violation exception (also called segmentation fault).

Answer (score 1):

First, C itself doesn't talk about segfaults, just undefined behaviour. But let's be practical and look at a typical Linux platform. If you access memory at a virtual address for which there's no mapping for your process, the kernel will send SIGSEGV to the process. When indexing in an array in static memory, you take the address of the array, add the offset, and dereference that. If the offset is far enough outside the valid range for the array, you can definitely reach an address that isn't mapped, and your process will segfault.

Comment: So in case of arrays in C on Linux, it does not matter whether the array is static (data segment) or dynamic(heap). I just get a seg fault when I get past the array index and access a page that the program does not have access to. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. Note, though, that the resulting address may very well happen to match some other data in your program, and therefore *not* cause a segfault.
When possible, test your program under valgrind. It's great for finding this type of issues.

Comment: SIGSEGV *is* defined in the C standard and in one place the standard also speaks of "segmentation violation".

Comment: Thanks for bringing it to my attention! You are right, SIGSEGV is defined in the spec, and "segmentation violation" /is/ mentioned in one place.
The requirements on `signal` and `SIGSEGV` seem vague enough that the implementation doesn't really need to do anything in particular, though. But again, thanks for pointing it out!